# Cordova Phonegap inappbrowser losing File Api functionality

Tags: ios, cordova, memory-leaks, inappbrowser, audiocontext

I am developing an app using Web Audio Api. I have discovered that there is a memory leak in the way that Safari handles audio and doesn't garbage college the Audio Context correctly.  For this reason I wish to load a new page. Have that page create the Audio Context, complete the operation and then close the window, so that the memory is released.

I have done the following to achieve this.

`ref = window.open('record.html', '_self');`  This will open the record.html page in the Cordova WebView according to https://wiki.apache.org/cordova/InAppBrowser

> 1 window.open('local-url.html');// loads in the
>   Cordova WebView
>   2 window.open('local-url.html', '_self');
>   // loads in the Cordova WebView

The record.html page loads a javascript file, that runs the operations that I wish to run.  Here is the recordLoad.js file that makes some calls to native operations ( The native API is only available if loaded in the Cordova Webview and as you can see I need to access the file system, so this is the only way I can see to do it.

```
    window.onload = createAudioContext;
ref = null;

function createAudioContext(){
    console.log('createAudioContext');
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    audioContext = new AudioContext;

    getDirectory();
}

function getDirectory(){
    console.log('getDirectory');
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, getFileSystem, fail);

}

function getFileSystem(directory){
    console.log('getFileSystem');
    var audioPath = localStorage.getItem('audioPath');
    directory.root.getFile(audioPath, null, getVocalFile, fail);

}

function getVocalFile(fileEntry){
    console.log('getVocalFile');
    fileEntry.file(readVocalsToBuffer, fail);

}

function readVocalsToBuffer(file){
    console.log('readVocalsToBuffer');
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt){
        var x = audioContext.decodeAudioData(evt.target._result, function(buffer){
            if(!buffer){
                console.log('error decoding file to Audio Buffer');
                return;
            }
            window.voiceBuffer = buffer;
            buffer = null;
            loadBuffers();
        });

    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}

//web
function loadBuffers(){
    console.log('loadBuffers');
    var srcSong = localStorage.getItem('srcSong');
    try{
        var bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(
            audioContext,
            [
                "."+srcSong
            ],
            createOffLineContext
        );
        bufferLoader.load()
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e.message);
    }
}


//
function createOffLineContext(bufferList){
    console.log('createOfflineContext');
    offline = new webkitOfflineAudioContext(2, window.voiceBuffer.length, 44100);
    var vocalSource = offline.createBufferSource();
    vocalSource.buffer = window.voiceBuffer;
    vocalSource.connect(offline.destination);

    var backing = offline.createBufferSource();
    backing.buffer = bufferList[0];
    backing.connect(offline.destination);

    vocalSource.start(0);
    backing.start(0);

    offline.oncomplete = function(ev){
        bufferList = null;
        console.log('audioContext');
        console.log(audioContext);
        audioContext = null;
        console.log(audioContext);
        vocalSource.stop(0);
        backing.stop(0);
        vocalSource.disconnect(0);
        backing.disconnect(0);
        vocalSource = null;
        backing = null;
        window.voiceBuffer = null;
        window.renderedFile = ev.renderedBuffer;
        var bufferR = ev.renderedBuffer.getChannelData(0);
        var bufferL = ev.renderedBuffer.getChannelData(1);
        var interleaved = interleave(bufferL, bufferR);
        var dataview = encodeWAV(interleaved);
        window.audioBlob = new Blob([dataview], {type: 'Wav'});

        saveFile();
    }

    offline.startRendering();

}
```

// This file is very long, but once it is finished mixing the two audio buffers it writes a new file to the file system.  And when that operation is complete I use

```
function gotFileWriter(writer){
console.log('gotFileWriter');
writer.onwriteend = function(evt){
    console.log('onwriteEnd');
    console.log(window.audioBlob);
    delete window.audioBlob;
    console.log(window.audioBlob);
   // checkDirectory();
    var ref = window.open('index.html', '_self');
   // ref.addEventListener('exit', windowClose);

}
writer.write(audioBlob);
```

}

I return back to the original index.html file. This solves the memory issues.  However, once I try to run the same operation a second time. ie load in the record.html file, and run the recordLoad.js file I receive an **error ReferenceError: Can't find variable: LocalFileSystem**

It would appear that in reload index.html some, but not all of the links to the Cordova API have been lost.  I can still for example use the Media Api but not the File Api.  I understand that this is a bit of a hacky way, (opening and closing windows) to solve the memory leak, but I cannot find any other way of doing it.  I really need some help with this. So any pointers very very welcome.

Comment: I've noted also that on the second time round running window.request(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,0, getFileSystem, fail) the code fails on that line, but if I pause the operation and enter that command directly into the console on Safari, the code executes without trouble. Puzzling?